# Remove element from JSON Array based on string match in shell script

Tags: json, shell, jq

I want to remove JSON Element based on the string match if it exist.

I am using the shell script.

Sample Input:

```
["https://test-ci.cmxdev.com/dev/AD-885/?oauth=callback",  
"https://test-ci.cmxdev.com/dev/INS-1676-a/?oauth=callback",  
"https://test-jdtest.cmxdev.com?oauth=callback",  
"https://localhost:3000?oauth=callback"]
```

Sample Output (Removed 2nd element):

```
["https://test-ci.cmxdev.com/dev/AD-885/?oauth=callback",   
"https://test-jdtest.cmxdev.com?oauth=callback",  
"https://localhost:3000?oauth=callback"]
```

Comment: What string-matching criterion do you have in mind? Please be specific. See also the mcve guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to make ti work using below method.

**Find the index of valid string**

```
callback_url_index=$(echo $json_output | jq -r '.UserPoolClient.CallbackURLs | index("https://test-jdtest.cmxdev.com?oauth=callback")');
```

**Remove Element based on found index**

```
if [ "$callback_url_index" != null ] ; then
  callbackURLs=$(echo $json_output | jq -r --arg callback_url_index "$callback_url_index" '.UserPoolClient.CallbackURLs | del(.['$callback_url_index'])')
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To remove all elements from an array equal to a particular value, you could "subtract" the value(s) from the array:

```
. - [.[1]]
```

Otherwise, the usual approach would be to rebuild and filter the array based on the conditions you want.

```
map(select(. != "https://test-ci.cmxdev.com/dev/INS-1676-a/?oauth=callback"))
```